# Pandas groupby difference between 2 most recent dates

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas Version: 1.1.0

Hello, I'm trying to find the difference in values between the last 2 dates of data_collected. While the code works fine when dealing with consecutive dates, I'm stuck on how to deal with weekends as no data is collected leaving a 2 day gap. This causes the groupby.diff() to ignore them.

with the following code I was able to slice out the 2 specific dates and get the results using .reindex_like()

```
# (working example when specifically slicing on 2 dates)
prior_date = df.loc[df['date_collected'] == '2020-11-06']
current = df.loc[df['date_collected'] == '2020-11-09']

prior_date = prior_date.set_index('date')['value']
current = current.set_index('date')['value']
prior_date = prior_date.reindex_like(current).fillna(0)

df = (current - prior_date).reset_index()
change = df[df['value'] != 0].dropna(axis=0)
```

However when I tried to mimic these results for an entire dataframe I was unable to find a way to use reindex_like on a multi index. Attempted to use .last() but then realized the weekends missing became an issue.

```
# (current result down below)
chng = df.set_index(['date_collected', 'date'])['value']
chng = chng.groupby(level=1).diff().reset_index()

last = df.groupby('date_collected')[['date', 'value']].last().reset_index()
chng = chng.set_index(['date_collected', 'value'])
last = last.set_index(['date_collected', 'value'])

chng = chng.fillna(last)
chng = chng[chng['value'] != 0].dropna()
```

```
# input data
+----------------+------------+-------+
| date_collected |    date    | value |
+----------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-06     | 2020-11-01 |     4 |
| 2020-11-06     | 2020-11-02 |     5 |
| 2020-11-06     | 2020-11-03 |     1 |
| 2020-11-06     | 2020-11-04 |     3 |
| 2020-11-06     | 2020-11-05 |     1 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-04 |     3 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-05 |     3 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-06 |     5 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-07 |     1 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-08 |     1 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-05 |     3 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-06 |     5 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-07 |     1 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-08 |     3 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-09 |     2 |
+----------------+------------+-------+

# wanted results
+----------------+------------+-------+
| date_collected |    date    | value |
+----------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-06     | 2020-11-05 |     1 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-05 |     2 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-06 |     5 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-07 |     1 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-08 |     1 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-08 |     2 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-09 |     2 |
+----------------+------------+-------+

# current results
+----------------+------------+-------+
| date_collected |    date    | value |
+----------------+------------+-------+
| 2020-11-06     | 2020-11-05 |     1 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-05 |     2 |
| 2020-11-09     | 2020-11-08 |     1 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-08 |     2 |
| 2020-11-10     | 2020-11-09 |     2 |
+----------------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to figure out reindexing the multi-index and get the wanted results with the following code:

```
dates = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max())
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['date_collected'].unique(), dates])

df = df.set_index(['date_collected', 'date'])
df = df.reindex(new_idx).fillna(0)

chng = df.groupby(level=1).diff()
chng = chng[chng['value'] != 0].dropna()
```